# CASE Statement - Same Condition Applies to More than one case

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, sum

```
Query:

    SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN app_id IN ('ICTO-115') THEN 'CASH_EQUITY' 
        WHEN app_id IN ('ICTO-115') THEN 'FX'
    END AS PRODUCT_LINE,
    sum(breaches) AS TOTAL
FROM metrics_daily M
WHERE app_id IN ('ICTO-115')
GROUP BY
    CASE 

        WHEN app_id IN ('ICTO-115') THEN 'CASH_EQUITY' 
        WHEN app_id IN ('ICTO-115') THEN 'FX'
    END;

Table

app_id      breaches
ICTO-115    26
ICTO-120    14
ICTO-569    45
ICTO-256    24
```

I have a case statement whereby app_id `ICTO-115` applies to more than one product but the sum of 26(number of breaches) only is showing for `CASH_EQUITY` as part of the GROUP BY. So the result as part of my query is only:

```
Product         TOTAL
CASH_EQUITY     26
```

My desired result would be:

```
Product         TOTAL
CASH_EQUITY     26
FX              26
```

What can I do to ensure that the `FX` is also shown with the `total` as 26. `ICTO-115` applies to both `FX` and `CASH_EQUITY`. I have many more app_ids where this scenario applies but I have tried giving a very simple example.

Comment: How come an ID applies to 2 different apps. An id itself means a unique relation.

Comment: A product can use more than one app/application

Answer (score 2):

You could start from a subquery that maps app_ids to product lines, and join it with the table:

```
select m.product_line, sum(breaches) total
from (
    select 'ICTO-115' app_id, 'CASH_EQUITY' product_line from dual
    union all
    select 'ICTO-115', 'FW' from dual
) p
inner join metrics_daily m on m.app_id = p.app_id
group by m.product_line
```

---

If you have a large number of app id / product lines mapping, it would be simpler to put them in a table, with each tuple on a separate row. You could then just replace the derived table (the subquery) with that mapping table.

Say table `app_to_product`:

```
app_id    | product_line
--------- | ------------
ICTO-115  | CASH_EQUITY
ICTO-115  | FW
```

Now the query can be written as:

```
select m.product_line, sum(breaches) total
from app_to_product p
inner join metrics_daily m on m.app_id = p.app_id
group by m.product_line
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the values in separate *columns* rather than *rows*:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN app_id IN ('ICTO-115') THEN breaches END) as CASH_EQUITY,
       (CASE WHEN app_id IN ('ICTO-115') THEN breaches END) as FX
FROM metrics_daily M
WHERE app_id IN ('ICTO-115')
```